# Eventstore sort by partical stream

Tags: javascript, typescript, projection, event-driven-design, eventstoredb

Im currently unable to create a new stream with a prefix, based on the other one.

one example stream can be:

```
person.admin
```

Ive been searching around the documentations https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v5/projections.html#user-defined-projections-api

wanted to try `fromstreamsmatching`, but:

```
fromStreamsMatching cant be done on a projections that  "one-time".
```

What do I need to do to allow my Continuous projection to work?

current behaviour:

```
0@user-
```

want:

```
0@user-{USERNAME OR ID}-result
```

how can I make the projection read from every user ( example `user-admin, user-test` ), and then return it in
`user-{username}-result`, or user-{username} and create a event with `type` of result?

**Projections:**

```
options({
    resultStreamName: "user-",
    $includeLinks: true,
    reorderEvents: false,
    processingLag: 500
})

fromCategory('user')
    .when({
        $init: function() {
            return {
                logins: 0,
            }
        },
        login: function(state, event) {
            state.logins += 1;
        },

    })
    .outputState()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a stateful partitioned continuous projection.

It needs to do the following:

- Partition the output state by the user id using the stream name
- Initialize the partition state by setting the login count to zero
- Optionally, initialize the shared state with the number of unique users and the total number of logins by setting both to zero
- Increase the login count by one for each new login event
- Optionally, increase the total login count in the shared state for each login event
- When the new partition is created (you got a new user), you can increase the number of users by one
- Output both states (notice the `biState` option) to separate streams. The shared state has a static stream name, and the partition state (per user) has a format string where the only argument is the partition id (user id in your case)

Here's the projection code that works:

```
options({
    $includeLinks: true,
    biState: true
})

fromCategory('user')
    .partitionBy(function (e) { 
        return e.streamId.split("-")[1];
    })
    .when({
        $init: function() {
            return {
                logins: 0,
            }
        },
        $initShared: function() {
            return {
                numberOfUsers: 0,
                totalLogins: 0
            }
        },
        $created: function (s, e) {
            s[1].numberOfUsers++;
        },
        "login": function(s, e) {
            s[0].logins++;
            s[1].totalLogins++;
            return s;
        },

    })
    .outputState()
    .outputTo("totalUsers", "logins-{0}");
```

When using the `biState`, you get an array in event handlers and in `$created`. The first element (index zero) is the partition state, and the second element (index one) is the shared state.

I tested it with two streams: `user-123` and `user-124`, and I emitted a couple of `login` events to both streams.

When I look at the projection, I see the shared state, and the field to enter the partition id:

[image: Shared state]

When I enter the partition id, I can see the partition state:

[image: Partition state]

You then can find `totalLogins` and `login-XXX` (by user) streams with the latest state. The `totalLogins` stream would actually contain links to individual `login-XXX` streams:

[image]

Here's how the event in `login-XXX` looks like:

[image]

When the projection emits a new state to the state streams, it also truncates the state stream. So, when you read the stream, I can suggest that you read backwards with the count one. In production, you'd need to scavenge the database regularly, otherwise, those truncated events will occupy a lot of space.

### Previous answer

> as the question was modified, the answer seems out of context

When I read the docs following the link in your question, I see this:

[image]

It says that the argument for the `forStreamMatching` function is a function that should return `true` of `false` given the stream name, like `stream => stream.startsWith("person.")`. I am not sure where the docs say that it would work with a string prefix.

A warning: the ES6 syntax is only supported in ESDB >= 21.10

Comment: yeah, but forstreammatching dosent work on continous projections anyway :|

Comment: By "does not work" you mean what exactly?

Comment: just that a dev said that forstreammatching is not working for my type of projections.